# Angular 11 - The legend in my highcharts are grouped and the output is not showing

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and angular 11.

I have this 3 mapped array that I want to show in my highcharts, but it seems that the quizname legend is in one grouped and not segregated and the passed and failed it not showing. I want it to be that every quizname is an individual legend.

Here is the html

```
<highcharts-chart 
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
></highcharts-chart>
```

Here is the ts

```
 getQuizRemarks(){

    this.dataService.getRemarks().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
  
        let chartDataPassed = res['quizRemarks'].map(res => res.Passed)
        let chartDataFailed = res['quizRemarks'].map(res => res.Failed)
        let quizName = res['quizRemarks'].map(res => res.Quiz_Title)
        console.log(chartDataPassed)
        console.log(chartDataFailed)
        console.log(quizName)

    this.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Truck Driver's Quiz Result"
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
    
        accessibility: {
            announceNewData: {
                enabled: true
            },
            point: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Score'
            }
    
        },
    
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
    
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
    
        series: [
            { 
                name: quizName,
                colorByPoint: false,
                data: [
                    {
                        name: "Passed",
                        y: chartDataPassed,

                    },
                    {
                        name: "Failed",
                        y: chartDataFailed,

                    }
                ]
            },

        ]

    };

  HC_exporting(Highcharts);
 })
    
}
```

Comment: Hi @reginald bollosa, Could you explain your problem more precisely and reproduce your current state in some online code editor, for example codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to run it in an online editor, but this is my codes. 

https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-shannon-b66wq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You can use this simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line as a base and only change the chart options.