# Angular 11 - How to import array data into highcharts

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, api, highcharts

I'm using angular 11, typescript

I have this array structure that I want to import in highcharts, but I don't know how to. I'm using api response to get the data and every time a user take a new quiz it adds another set of quiz_title, passed and failed.

```
 "message": "Remarks successfuly shown",
    "error": false,
    "error code": 200,
    "line": "line215215",
    "quizRemarks": [
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "Acts and Regulation",
            "Passed": "24",
            "Failed": "6"
        },
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "Breakdowns and Accidents",
            "Passed": "7",
            "Failed": "3"
        },
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "Coupling and Uncoupling Semi-Trailers",
            "Passed": "2",
            "Failed": "8"
        },
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "Defensive Driving",
            "Passed": "2",
            "Failed": "37"
        },
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "Driver Health and Safety",
            "Passed": "7",
            "Failed": "1"
        },
        {
            "Quiz_Title": "General Knowledge",
            "Passed": "4",
            "Failed": "14"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is my attempt 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388616/angular-11-the-legend-in-my-highcharts-are-grouped-and-the-output-is-not-showi

Answer (score 1):

Is this an output that you want to achieve?

```
const chartData = dataFromServer.map(data => ({
  name: data["Quiz_Title"],
  data: [{
      name: 'Passed',
      y: parseInt(data["Passed"])
    },
    {
      name: 'Failed',
      y: parseInt(data["Failed"])
    }
  ]
}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dz1wheut/

Comment: Yes that is the output that I want, here is my code I tried it and it's not working

https://jsfiddle.net/08v5bzgw/#&togetherjs=0a21RJhOQN

Comment: It's not working because it's not Angular envoirment.